# Highcharts: get category name on column click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am a highcharts rookie and it seems like a very simple problem, but I am unable to **get x axis category** when I click on a column in a very simple column chart.

What I tried without success:

- `this`,
- `x`, `this.x`,
- Having a look at the chart object (within my browser with developer tools) itself to see if there would be anything useful in its structure itself, but I don't seem to find what I need.

Here is a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/9xskkkpx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
column: {
    events: {
        click:function(event) {
            alert(event.point.category);
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xskkkpx/1/

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.events.click

Comment: Damn I was too focused on using `this` thinking it was the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: @Barbara Laird how can i get the name if i want to use hover?

Comment: @John The tooltip formatter functions have access to the point object.  If you need more than that, you should ask another question